# Div element jumping down

Tags: html, css

Hey beginner coder here:

I'm trying to achieve this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crbpg.png with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Uppgift 5</title>
<style>
    body{
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #text{
        width: 90%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #text p{
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    #image{

        height: 500px;
        width: 5%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url("bakgrund.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="text">
        <p>
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        </p>
        <p>
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextv
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        </p>
        <p>
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextv
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="image">

    </div>
</div>
```

but I fail and get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy2wU.jpg what am I doing wrong? I've tried things like adding minus margin values. Why is it jumping down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
#text,
#image { vertical-align: top; }
```

The reason is because `inline-block` elements are, by default, aligned by their baselines - so the bottom of both div's are in line with each other - meaning that their will be a space at the top of the shorter div when it's placed in line with a taller div to make the bottoms of these divs line up.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin-top: 25px; ///Remove this
}
```

Add `margin-top: 0` in body tag